# Facebook Authorization with OmniAuth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

Now I am trying to set a Facebook Authorization system. But I got an erro message and don't know why. Could you give me some advice??

Error message:

```
{
   "error": {
  "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: \u6307\u5b9a\xxxx\u308c\u305fURL\u306f\u3001\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u30b1\u30fc\u30b7\u30e7\u30f3\u306e\u8a2d\u5b9a\u3067\u8a31\u53ef\u3055\u308c\u3066\u3044\u307e\u305b\u3093\u3002",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 191
    }
}
```

What I did is as follows;

①Gemfile

```
    gem 'omniauth'
    gem 'omniauth-facebook'
```

②bundle install

③config
/config/initializers/omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook,"App ID","App Secret"
end
```

※Site URL on facebook dev

```
http://127.0.0.1
```

④app/views/layout/application.html.erb
    <%= link_to "Facebook Login", "/auth/facebook" %>

⑤config/routes.rb

```
#OmniAuth
  match "/auth/:provider/callback" => "sessions#callback"
  match "/logout" => "sessions#destroy", :as=>:logout
  match '/auth/failure', to: redirect('/')
```

⑥/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def callback
    raise request.env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the Site URL on facebook dev as your system IP address like `http://192.168.88.9999:3000` and 
run the application with IP address

Hope this will  help you :)

Comment: Mr. DEbadatt, Thank you so much for your comment. I put http://'my ip address':3000 on my facebook dev. But it didn't work.

Comment: Did you run the application with your IP on browser?

Comment: Now I understand you. I tried and made it. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Then, I am now facing a new problem. This is the error message after login..RuntimeError at /auth/facebook/callback
--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
provider: facebook
uid: 'xxxxxxx'
info: !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash
  nickname:

Answer (score 0):

You must have created your apps page on facebook, go there and edit your site url. If you are on local server then use `http://localhost:3000` if 3000 is your port number

Comment: Mr/Mis user2675613, thank you for your advice, but I tried so many times with http://localhost:3000 and it failed.

Comment: @KuniharuAramaki you need to use `http://localhost:3000` and not just localhost:3000 and if you would've simply used localhost:3000 then it would have gave you Site URL must use the HTTP or HTTPS protocols error so use the it with "http"

Comment: Thank you again. I will confirm again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the site URL at the facebook devloper's app setting. I hope that it will help you.

```
From http://127.0.0.1 to http://localhost
```